# Preserve h2 database between tests of individual modules of a maven multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, h2

I have (flat) a multi module project with roughly the following structure:

- parent (pom)

  - A (jar)
  - B (jar)
  - C (jar)
  - D (war)

Module D depends on A, B and C and packages everything in a war. Each of the jar modules (A, B and C) have JUnit-based integration tests using an embedded H2 database (they are `@SpringBootTest`, run with the `SpringRunner`).

The database is simply setup using properties inside a specialised test profile:

```
spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:def;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Currently, when running a `mvn install` on the parent, the database is created before each module's build is run (i.e. the database is destroyed after each module's build).

Is it possible to somehow preserve the database between the build of each module? The reason being that the setup of the database is a rather time-consuming operation.

Comment: You could define it as embedded database `h2:file` pointing to a path that is safe during the build, e.g. does not get wiped.

Comment: I also though a little about that, and I might fall back to that if there is no other solution... One problem would be that I would like the DB to indeed be generated during this overall build run; if we have a file, it might be there since a while ago (and cause conflicts with the current definition). Might be an idea tho to delete the DB file very early on in the `clean` goal...

Comment: What about only using unittest in the jars and put the integration tests on the war level? That way you launch spring only once.

Comment: That would be for sure my recommended approach, but unfortunately there are several issues blocking this. Technically, there are actually several war's generated and most modules are used between the war. Practically, it is too late in the lifetime of this project to actually introduce such a change...

Comment: @mrkernelpanic: If you post your comment as an answer, I would upvote it. If I don't find a better way, then I would also accept it in the following days :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment you could place the integration tests into the war module so that the spring context needs to run only once. This would speed up the build quite a bit, if the context is big. You keep the simple unittests in the jar modules.

If, as you wrote have several war assemblies and moving the tests into those would be alot of work, I would suggest adding one maven module for testing purposes. This could even be a war so you can run e2e tests against it. 
I manage an application like this, where the business modules are jars and the final assemblies are wars.

Adding a module will not interfere with the current build and you can move tests one-by-one from the existing place into the new module. This proved to be not to much work and speeds up the build in total.

Our project consists now of 96 modules and 2 test modules. We started the same way as you and after 1 to 2 days the testing modules where ready. The jars build very fast as it‘s just compilation. So this is not a limiting factor.

Edit: As I just read your question again, and the time consuming part is really the database creation upfront, the suggestion about a file database instead of a memory database is also interesting. You can build the h2 db file once and place this as a resource into your testing module. On startup h2 will just have to connect, and potentially validate, and you should be running within seconds. One problem i see here is, if you use, for example, flyway and want to test your migration scripts. This would have to be mitigated somehow.